# urlManager not working in Yii 2.0

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, yii, yii2

I'm trying to learn yii 2.0 and currently i'm using `basic` version of yii 2.0. First step was to configure urls. So as per the guide, i enabled `mod_rewrite`, checked it using `phpinfo()` and then added following lines in the `components` of `config/web.php`:

```
‘urlManager’ => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
],
```

Now i expect `http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site/test` to work as `http://localhost/basic/web/index.php/site/test`

But it takes me to the `index` method of `SiteController`. Actually it's taking all urls to `index` method. Part after `index.php` doesn't matters. Even a wrong `controllerId/actionId` works. What could be the problem?

Here's my `config/web.php`

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'tSjCFs0He7lBeZN34fLzFij2xUUE4NwK',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        ‘urlManager’ => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
}

return $config;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to configure `apache` as well. As [Yii's official guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#recommended-apache-configuration-) says:

**Recommended Apache Configuration**

```
# Set document root to be "basic/web"
DocumentRoot "path/to/basic/web"

<Directory "path/to/basic/web">
# use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward the request to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

# ...other settings...
```

You can also create a `.htaccess` file into your web directory with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

On the other hand, you must change ` to ' like below:

```
'urlManager' => [ //you wrote `urlManager` which must change to 'urlManager'
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

---

**UPDATE**

**recommended Nginx Configuration**

```
server {
charset utf-8;
client_max_body_size 128M;

listen 80; ## listen for ipv4
#listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

server_name mysite.local;
root        /path/to/basic/web;
index       index.php;

access_log  /path/to/basic/log/access.log main;
error_log   /path/to/basic/log/error.log;

location / {
    # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# uncomment to avoid processing of calls to non-existing static files by Yii
#location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|gif|swf|ico|pdf|mov|fla|zip|rar)$ {
#    try_files $uri =404;
#}
#error_page 404 /404.html;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    try_files $uri =404;
}

location ~ /\.(ht|svn|git) {
    deny all;
}
}
```

[Recommended Nginx Configuration](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md#recommended-nginx-configuration-)

Comment: Added `.htaccess` to `www/basic/`. Still same result.

Comment: @Kanav replace `‘urlManager’ ` with `'urlManager'`

Comment: @Kanav Ooops, and also put the `.htaccess` file into `/www/basic/web` directory . Not in `www/basic/`

Comment: @AliMasudianPour what about for nginx server?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour does this nginx config include the config necessary for the PrettyUrls to work?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour I still could get the urls to work with the demo basic site on /var/www/basic using nginx . Can you help?

Comment: @aliMasudianPour I try what you describe for apache server but I am getting the error "Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration" in server error log

Comment: @AliMasudianPour i am using nginx server but when use 'enablePrettyUrl' => true in yii2 then it gives error.