# Yii 2.0 hiding /basic/web from the URL along with the index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii, url-rewriting, yii2

Plenty of information around the net on how to hide the index.php from your Yii 2.0 application URL, however, what I'm trying to do here is to also remove the '/basic/web/' from the URL. /basic/web is the directory from which the application is running and the configuration that I have so far is the following. That goes into the config file:

```
'urlManager' =>[
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
        ],
```

And this is my htaccess file that I have within the /web folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So far, so good, I can access something directly calling `mysite.com/basic/web/controller/action`. What do I need to do though to remove the /basic/web so that the URL becomes just simple `mysite.com/controller/action`?

Any tips welcome, thanks!

EDIT: I'm looking for a way without touching the apache configuration file as I don't have access to it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26459414/urlmanager-not-working-in-yii-2-0/26463551#26463551

Comment: Seeing that, let me edit my question as I don't have access to the apache configuration file so I'm looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define your apache configuration in another way. Your site should point to {folder}/basic/web and not to {folder}.

Because you changed the requirements:

For a cpanel setup you should:
1) remove the silly basic folder, what is the point of it anyway? Just because Yii installs that way does not mean you have to keep it. So move everything 1 level up.
2) Rename web to public_html make sure you rename it in some files too (config/bootstrap comes to mind).

Yes you can do it with .htaccess but you should not have the files exposed to the internet, just your web folder should be exposed so I am not giving you that solution because it is not a good one.

Comment: Is there a way to do it only through the .htaccess file in case I don't have access to the apache configuration file?

Comment: is this a Cpanel setup or anything similar? is this on a live server?

Comment: It's shared hosting environment that doesn't allow edits to the configuration file. I do have the option to request to their support to add some custom code to it but if I have to do that for each single application, that would become quite troublesome process.

Comment: It's not a cpanel unfortunately but per your suggestion, I guess I can live with just '/web' in the URL or even rename it to something more appropriate.

Comment: I have not seen a hosting company that does not allow you to do what I described. If you do know one move as you will loose more time in the future going around silly restrictions.

Comment: They do not have cpanel but they have their own customized hosting panel instead which is quite nice. As a result there's not public_html folder in their structure at all.

Comment: They must have 1 level before the actual web folder. If they do you can do the changes I said.

Comment: I think they have it the other way around. They let you in 1 level inside the web folder where you have a public folder "mysite.com" which is accessible through the web and other directories which are not. You cannot rename the "mysite.com" folder though so I don't think I can implement the changes you suggested. It's a nice tip though!

Comment: rename web to misite.com

Comment: At the end of the day, that remains to be the best solution. Thank you very much for the input!

Answer (score 7):

```
RewriteEngine on
# Change yourdomain.com to be your primary domain.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/basic/web/

# Don't change this line.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /basic/web/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourdomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ basic/web/index.php [L]
```

Change .htaccess permissions to 440 when you're done. Nothing to fear using this method, contrary to what is stated by Mihai P.

Comment: I actually thought "The use of .htaccess files is discouraged as they can have a detrimental effect on server performance. Only use them when necessary." source: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Htaccess . Even if he cannot get around using a .htaccess file why put another condition in it when you can do it like I said?  Isn't this a better practice (having only 1 file exposed) then what you suggest? This is the reason why Yii, Laravel, etc have 1 folder exposed to the internet and not their entire app folder. Anyway just my 2c, I would rather educate then give answers to wrong questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Working Solution is Here!

Step 1. in yii2 basic application directory create  an index.php file and fill it as below

```
<?php

// comment out the following two lines when deployed to production
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php';

$config = require __DIR__ . '/config/web.php';

(new yii\web\Application($config))->run();
```

Step 2. Create a .htaccess file in the same base directory as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```