# Hide web from URL in Yii2

Tags: url-rewriting, yii2

I have followed answer described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178364/yii-2-0-hiding-basic-web-from-the-url-along-with-the-index-php). I have moved Application files and folder to one level up as suggested.

`public_html/basic/web,config etc..` to `public_html/web,config etc..`

Removed index.php from url by modifying these configuration:

config/web.php

```
'urlManager' =>[
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
    ],
```

htaccess file in web folder

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So now my url is `example.com/web/controller/action`

How can I hide web from the url above? I don't have access to the apache configuration file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer still stands :).

You are on the right track, move everything 1 directory lower. Right now you copied the entire yii2 application in public_html, you should move it 1 directory down. Then copy everything you have in web in public_html. By doing this all your scripts are not exposed to the web, only 1 index.php will be exposed and that is the proper way to have it set up.

Also this is the main tutorial for yii that tells you how to do it https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md

Do not be afraid of doing this, take the blue pill (or is it red) :).

Comment: Thanks @Mihai, It was as easy as just moving 1 level up.

Comment: It is not very good idea due to security reasons. It'll be better to keep framework core away of public folder.

Comment: The core is still away from the public, only the index.php file is exposed. I am not saying you should move the index.php 1 level up, move everything 1 level up.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add in config\web

```
$baseUrl = str_replace('/web', '', (new Request)->getBaseUrl());

$config = [
'defaultRoute' => $baseUrl,
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
    ]
],
'urlManager' => [
    'baseUrl' => $baseUrl,
 ]
```

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/755/how-to-hide-frontend-web-in-url-addresses-on-apache/